# RegEx Match whole line with first occurrence from the bottom of the file, upwards

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to parse a file with error codes.
I would only like the first occurrence from the bottom of the file to be returned.

So far, I've got this regex searching for the error code numbers, and it returns the whole line with the Multiline option, but it returns all lines in the file, not just the last one.

```
^.*?\b(639|640|460|458|664|148)\b.*$
```

I'm using powershell, so if you have an example using powershell - that would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: If it is possible to show us some sample input that would be great ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your regex is correct for matching on a line then you should be able to do something like this:

```
$pattern = '^.*?\b(639|640|460|458|664|148)\b.*$'
$content = Get-Content c:\somefile.txt
for ($i = $content.Length - 1; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
    if ($content[$i] -match $pattern) {
        $matches[1]
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `Select-String` for this:

```
$filename = 'C:\path\to\input.txt'
$pattern  = '\b(639|640|460|458|664|148)\b'

Get-Content $filename | Select-String $pattern | select -Last 1
```